# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with ArrayAdapter with filter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with the given below custom implementation of an `ArrayAdapter` with filtering enabled. I see the filtering code returning the correct resultset, but when view is rendered after filtering, I get an exception. What am I doing wrong here. Any help  is appreaciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.syntrio.iwm.act.R;

public class IWMArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{

    Activity activity;
    List<T> mItems;
    String[] icons;
    boolean isArrowNeeded=false;
    boolean isIconNeeded=false;
    private ItemsFilter mFilter;


    public IWMArrayAdapter(Activity context,List<T> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_row,items);
        activity=context;
        mItems=items;
    }

    public void setIcons(String[] iconList){
        if(iconList!=null && iconList.length>0){
            icons=iconList;
            isIconNeeded=true;
        }
    }
    public void setArrowNeeded(){
        isArrowNeeded=true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_array, parent, false);
        }
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(mItems.get(position).toString());
        ImageView icon;
        ImageView arrow;
        if(isIconNeeded){
            icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
            if(icons.length==1){
                icon.setImageResource(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(icons[0], "drawable", "com.syntrio.iwm.act"));
            }
            else{
                icon.setImageResource(activity.getResources().getIdentifier(icons[position], "drawable", "com.syntrio.iwm.act"));
            }
            icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(isArrowNeeded){
            arrow = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_arrow);
            arrow.setImageResource(activity.getResources().getIdentifier("arrow", "drawable", "com.syntrio.iwm.act"));
            arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        return (row);
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemsFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;

    }

    private class ItemsFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = mItems;
                results.count = mItems.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<T> itemsList = new ArrayList<T>();

                for (T t : mItems) {
                    if (t.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        itemsList.add(t);
                }

                results.values = itemsList;
                results.count = itemsList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0){
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
            else {

                List<T> lst = (List<T>)results.values;
                 List<T> itemsList = new ArrayList<T>(lst);
                 //this.items=mItems;
                mItems =itemsList;              
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Exception is :

```
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.syntrio.iwm.IWMArrayAdapter.getView(IWMArrayAdapter.java:50)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-24 16:52:11.608: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Update : added exception

Comment: Could you also post the error log you get?

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the exception.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Added stacktrace

Comment: check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13158428/1752867

Comment: if (results != null && results.count >= 0) {
                 //if results of search is not  null set the searched results data
               } else {
                  // set original values
               }

               notifyDataSetInvalidated();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403. You can refer to the sample in the link

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement the [getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29) method within your custom `ArrayAdapter`. The `ListView` invokes that method on its adapter to find out how many items it will display. You need something like this:

```
public int getCount () {
    return mItems.size ();
}
```